# how to show MBProgressHUD after removing from superView.?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5, mbprogresshud

My `MBProgressHUD` is not show after i removing from `superview`. when I first time remove `superview` after that I almost sow but does not visible. 
my code is

```
if(condition)  
{

    HUD.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark.png"]];

    [HUD bringSubviewToFront:HUD];

    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;

    HUD.labelText = @"Unfollowed";

    [HUD hide:YES afterDelay:0.5];

}

[HUD hide:YES];

[HUD removeFromSuperViewOnHide];
```

after that I show once again it

```
[HUD show:YES];
```

but this method don't display it. please help me

Comment: remove this code [HUD removeFromSuperViewOnHide]; and try